# What pnp and ptp means in smarty?

Tags: html, smarty, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop invoice footer smarty template file, there is this code:

```
{literal}{:pnp:} / {:ptp:}{/literal}
```

What the pnp and ptp means?

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of the current page (pnp) et the number of the total of pages (ptp).
Good luck to get nice pdf !

Answer (score 0):

`{:pnp:} / {:ptp:}` are most likely some other library's markup that would otherwise be incorrectly parsed by Smarty (since the `{}`) therefore are encapsulated into `{literal}`.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal
[Example with literals `{:pnp:}`](http://scm.prestashop.com/rdiff/PrestaShop_v.1.5?csid=43a4083dee71d73c012f36819a3d767ad5d3875c&u&N)

`{:pnp:}` serves as a placeholder for page number and `{:ptp:}` serves as a placeholder for total number of pages. They are used in PDF libraries for different functions, in FPDF for sure, probably in TCPDF as well. If you see the placeholder instead of an integer your pdf generation failed at some point.

Comment: Just wanted to add for information if someone stumbles upon this question and will be wondering what they are: {:pnp:} serves as a placeholder for page number and {:ptp:} serves as a placeholder for total number of pages. They are used in PDF libraries for different functions, in FPDF for sure, probably in TCPDF as well. If you see the placeholder instead of an integer your pdf generation failed at some point.